# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Medical Sciences breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  6         16
Users destroyed                                  62          0
Users deleted                                    25          0
Users contacted                                  12          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue            12        388
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue                1        209
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue          2        286
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                1        184
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                 1      1,283
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue               61      2,750
Tags merged                                       1          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             2          0
Tag synonyms created                              2          0
Questions unprotected                             0          1
Questions reopened                               19         10
Questions protected                               9         55
Questions migrated                               25          0
Questions flagged⁴                                1      1,205
Questions closed                                534        640
Question flags handled⁴                         589        617
Posts unlocked                                    0          6
Posts undeleted                                  12         23
Posts locked                                      2        115
Posts deleted⁵                                  344      1,477
Posts bumped                                      0        142
Escalations to the CM team                        4          0
Comments undeleted                               10          0
Comments flagged                                  0        256
Comments deleted⁶                               534        840
Comment flags handled                           158         98
Answers flagged                                   4      1,024
Answer flags handled                            617        411
All comments on a post moved to chat             12          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Medical Sciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...